# Why is the resistance proportional to the length squared in a wire?

Tags: electrical-resistance, dimensional-analysis

I don't understand why the $R∝L^2$ (given that the volume doesn't change.) Eg: If the resistance of a wire is $3 \ \Omega$ and the length extends by $1.5$x the amount, then the new resistance will be $6.25$, so it increased by $1.5^2$ (if volume remains constant.)

No matter what I do/try, I keep getting $R∝L$ (meaning that $R=1.5$).

If $L∝1/A$ and $A∝1/R$, then that means that $R$ would be equal to 1.5 (so should increase by $1.5$x the amount), as $1.5=1/A$, so $A=1/1.5$ (which is equivalent to 2/3), so $R$ must be = to $1/(2/3)$ which gets $1.5$ the amount.

I've tried other methods too, but no matter what I try, it keeps saying $R=1.5$, when it should =$1.5^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the wire gets longer, it also gets thinner. If you increase the length, that increases the resistance. If you decrease the area, that does too. That should be enough of a hint to figure out the rest.

Comment: Ahh yes, I figured it out thanks. I didn't take both the thinning of the wire and the increase in length into consideration (when they both have an effect on the resistance.)